# Symfony2 Multiple Firewalls: Logs out from other firewall

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, firewall

I have **2 firewalls** (one for the **admin panel** and one for the **registered users**) and **2 in-memory providers** (one for the **admin** and one for the **registered users**) for my Symfony2 application -- too dynamic huh?

Now, I tried to access a route for **registered users**, Boom! I am presented with a BasicAuth dialog as expected.

Next, when I tried to access a route for **admin**, I am again presented with another BasicAuth dialog -- as expected too.

However, when I navigate back to any **registered users**' route, I am again presented with the BasicAuth dialog to which I conclude that everytime I am asked for my credentials with the authentication dialog of the firewall that matches the route I am navigating, I was automatically logged out from the other firewall.

Here is my `security.yml` file.

```
security:

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        walang_forever:
            memory: 
                users:
                    user:
                        password: test
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
        nailad_forever:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: test
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin_gugma:
            pattern: ^/admin
            http_basic: 
                provider: nailad_forever

        main_gugma:
            pattern: ^/user
            http_basic:
                provider: walang_forever

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

All I want is just to login once per firewall.

Any similar experiences? Or proposed solution?

Comment: Try this [http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context)

Answer (score 2):

Use the invalidate_session: false on both logout firewall settings:

```
logout:
    path:             mylogoutpath
    target:           MyBundle_homepage
    invalidate_session: false
```

The invalidate_session: false does the trick.
See: https://codingformat.com